# SQL (server 2008) retrieve (distinct) data from different tables (stored in a new table's column)

Tags: sql, sql-server, subquery, dynamic-sql, information-schema

here's the issue. I have several tables with oil wells data inside. Most of them (not all of them) have an UWI -which stands for Unique Well Identifier- and a WELL_NAME columns. I've managed to use a query which lets me know which tables have UWI and WELL_NAME columns (using INFORMATION_SCHEMA). I've saved this as a new table (UWITABLES). The tricky part (for me) has been  to get a "Master" table (of UWIs and Well Names) from all of the tables I got from that INFORMATION_SCHEMA Query.
I've tried the Union approach, but to be honest, the list of tables I got has sufficient tables to make me look for a different approach (hopefully one that takes advantage of the list of tables I got).

The overall scenario is like this:

- I need to get a table with the following columns:

> ```
> ********************************
> *  UWI  |  WELL_NAME  |  TABLE *
> ********************************
> ```

The UWI, Well names and the table from which that entry originates.

- Some tables have repeated UWIs and Well Names (some wells are tested on different depth intervals, so for these "tests" tables, I will have repeated UWIs and Well Names). So I need to get a list of wells with no repetition at table level:

TABLE_A:

> ```
> ********************************************
> *   UWI    |    WELL_NAME   |  TEST_NUMBER *
> ********************************************
> *  005     |      Well 1    |      1       *
> ********************************************
> *  005     |      Well 1    |      2       *
> ********************************************
> *  005     |      Well 1    |      3       *
> ********************************************
> *  007     |      Well 3    |      1       *
> ********************************************
> *  007     |      Well 3    |      2       *
> ********************************************
> ```

TABLE_B:

> ```
> ********************************************
> *   UWI    |    WELL_NAME   |  PROD_OIL    *
> ********************************************
> *  005     |      Well 1    |      52131   *
> ********************************************
> *  006     |      Well 2    |      54364   *
> ********************************************
> *  008     |      Well 4    |      34538   *
> ********************************************
> *  009     |      Well 5    |      1886    *
> ********************************************
> ```

Resulting table:

> ```
> *********************************
> *  UWI  |  WELL_NAME  |  TABLE  *
> *********************************
> *  005  |    Well 1   | TABLE_A *
> *********************************
> *  005  |    Well 1   | TABLE_B *
> *********************************
> *  006  |    Well 2   | TABLE_B *
> *********************************
> *  007  |    Well 3   | TABLE_A *
> *********************************
> *  008  |    Well 4   | TABLE_B *
> *********************************
> *  009  |    Well 5   | TABLE_B *
> *********************************
> ```

Order by UWI is not a must, just thought of putting it like this so it's less messy. If possible, I'd like to benefit from your expertise and get a brief and simple explanation on how you constructed the query. If a simple answer is possible, I'd appreciate that. I'm just starting here. Thanks to all in advance!

-Mike

Comment: a union is the way to go honestly.  what was your issue with the union?  do you have an example of how you used union?

Comment: Sorry for the late response... I have 50+ different tables with UWIs and WELL_NAMES... thought it was worthy looking for a different approach rather that using union +50 times.

Comment: either way you're doing +50 selects.  `Union` will take some extra processing to eliminate duplicates though, so you will need to consider that if your tables have a bunch of rows.  Same with `Distinct` and `Group By`

Answer (score 0):

Try this query

```
select uwi,well_name,'Table1' as table
from table1
Group by Uwi,Well_name
Union all
select uwi,well_name,'Table2' as table
from table2
Group by Uwi,Well_name
```

or

```
select distinct uwi,well_name,'Table1' as table
    from table1    
    Union all
    select distinct uwi,well_name,'Table2' as table
    from table2
```

Answer (score 0):

Union should work for you. If you have a table with the table names you need you can build a dynamic query like this.

```
DECLARE @Sql VARCHAR(MAX)
SELECT @Sql = COALESCE(@Sql + ' UNION ', '') 
    + 'SELECT UWI, WELL_NAME,' + [TableName] + ' AS [Table] FROM ' + [TableName]
FROM UWITABLES

EXEC (@Sql)
```

`UNION` will give you `DISTINCT UWI, WELL_NAME, TABLE`